# Delete elements of a JSON encoded in a $_COOKIE

Tags: php, arrays, json, cookies

Good morning! In the code below, I did a programming logic to delete an element in a JSON, but it is encoded within a $_COOKIE.

```js
<?php
  $desire = json_decode($_COOKIE['desire']);
  
  // JSON before deletion from the unset() function
  
  echo print_r($desire)."<hr>";
  
  unset($desire[0]);
  
  $desire = json_decode(print_r($desire))."<hr>";
  
  // JSON after deletion from the unset() function
  
  echo json_encode($desire)[0]."<hr>";
  
  // This function does not work, the variable $_COOKIE ['desire'] remains the same
  
  setcookie('desire', json_encode(json_decode(print_r($desire))), time() + 604800);
?>
```

```html
Result (html):

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id_book] => 13 [qtd_book] => 1 [vl_book] => 57.6 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id_book] => 20 [qtd_book] => 1 [vl_book] => 105.5 ) ) 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Array ( [1] => stdClass Object ( [id_book] => 20 [qtd_book] => 1 [vl_book] => 105.5 ) )
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**QUESTION:** What is the most correct way to solve this problem? In the last line of PHP, the setcookie() function does not update the array with the index deleted for the $_COOKIE variable in the page store. Are there other solutions to work with this type of information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last line should simply be:

```php
setcookie('desire', json_encode($desire), time() + 604800);
```

**EDIT:** But this line

```php
 $desire = json_decode(print_r($desire))
```

does not make much sense, it should not be there at all. `print_r` should be used to display values in a human-readable form and - without a second argument explicitly set to `true` - its return value does not make much sense.

**EDIT #2: Complete cleaned up solution**

```php
<?php
  $desire = json_decode($_COOKIE['desire']);
  
  // Value of $desire before unset(). 
  print_r($desire);
  echo '<hr>';
  
  // Unsetting element with index 0.
  // Beware! 0 may not always be the first available index.
  // If removing of the first element is desired, regardless its index, array_shift($desire) should be used instead.
  unset($desire[0]);

  // Value of $desire after unset().
  print_r($desire);
  echo '<hr>';
  
  // Save the new $desire value in the cooke.  
  setcookie('desire', json_encode($desire), time() + 604800);
?>
```

Comment: the last line generated this result: 
`$_COOKIE['desire'] = "1`
and yet this error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot unset string offsets in desire.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in desire.php on line 1`

Comment: Even without the print_r function inside `json_decode` or even adding `true` as a `print_r` parameter, the error continues. In fact, `json_encode($desire)` is equal to:

`{"1": {"id_book": "18", "qtd_book": "1", "vl_book": "23.5"}, "2": {"id_book": "17", "qtd_book": "1 "," vl_book ":" 45.7 "}," 3 ": {" id_book ":" 22 "," qtd_book ":" 1 "," vl_book ":" 164.99 "}}`

Now the problem is in the final result, the variable `$_COOKIE['desire']` cannot be the beginning of the result of `json_encode($desire)` equal to `"1`, it has to be an array with the index excluded.

Comment: @zoli.szabo thank you very much for your help! I posted this same question in three communities here at StackOverflow, no one answered and my account was even blocked, but your contribution was the only one that really solved my problem. Congratulations! I am speechless with so much emotion that I was.